# Active Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've inherited a SharePoint 2010 site with many page layouts. I am attempting to determine which page layout is active and update it with the SharePoint 2010 Designer without modifying every one of the layouts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Pages library and either edit the view or add a new view that contains the column called "Page Layout".  That way you can see which page layouts are in use.

Comment: Understood. But how do I know the one that is actively being used?

Comment: the Page Layout column will be a link to the Page Layout in the master page gallery.  You'll be able to edit that in the SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Yes. I can edit the file, but I can't tell which layout is active being used by the master page. How can I tell?

Comment: I'm confused because a site can only have one or two master pages that are in use at any one time.  That master page + the Pages list item + its associated Page Layout is what drives the display of any one give page in a site.  Looking at the Page Layout column of the Pages library is the only way to say which Page Layouts are currently being used in the site.

Comment: I think thats the answer I was looking for. I've been looking in the Designer for the association between the page and the page layout used. I'm looking the "Site Pages" list but don't see the page layouts associated.